# Kronos API v2 - including multiple query parameters in a request

Tags: kronos-workforce-central, kronos-workforce-ready-suite

I am trying to access the [Time Entries](https://secure.saashr.com/ta/docs/rest/public/?r=__v2__companies__(cid)__time-entries#) object via the Kronos API v2.

The documentation says that there are two required Query Parameters: `start_date` and `end_date`.

I am able to query the endpoint including one of the parameters at a time but am not able to enter both.  And, I find the documentation quite lacking.

The root of the endpoint is:

```
https://secure.saashr.com/ta/rest/v2/companies/{cid}/time-entries
```

Here are things I have tried to suffix to the above endpoint:

```
?start_date=2019-11-01&end_date=2019-12-01
?start_date=2019-11-01|end_date=2019-12-01
?start_date=2019-11-01 end_date=2019-12-01
?start_date=2019-11-01?end_date=2019-12-01
?start_date=2019-11-01:end_date=2019-12-01
?filter=start_date:=:2019-11-01|end_date:=:2019-12-01
```

I also tried including quotes around the dates.

Everything results in some 400 level error when querying the API.  With most of the above suffixes, it recognizes `start_date` but not the `end_date`.  In this case, the error is:

```
{'code': 400, 'message': 'Missing required: end_date'}]
```

Note, above `{cid}` is replaced with the company's id.

In summary, how should I include two query parameters in the Kronos API?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is correct.

```
https://secure.saashr.com/ta/rest/v2/companies/{cid}/time-entries?start_date=2019-11-01&end_date=2019-12-01
```

should work just fine.

Could you provide full URL you set in request?